# parsing excel style formula

Tags: python, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, formula

I am working on building formula reference map from spreadsheet xml using python. formula is like

```
=IF(AND(LEN(R[-2]C[-1])>0,R[-1]C),WriteCurve(OFFSET(R16C6, 0,0,R9C7,R10C7),R15C6,R10C3, R8C3),"NONE")
```

I am only interested in getting nth argument of writecurve function. here i comes up very C style program basically counting coma which is not inside bracket. there are a lot of nested formula

```
def parseArguments(t, func, n):
start=t.find(func)+len(func)+1
bracket = 0
ss = t[start:]
lastcomma = 0
for i, a in enumerate(ss):
    if a=="(":
        bracket +=1
    elif a==")":
        if bracket==0:
            break
        bracket-=1
    elif a == ",":
        if bracket==0 and n==0:
            break
        elif bracket ==0:
            if n-1==0:
                lastcomma = i
            n-=1
if lastcomma == 0:
    return ss[:i]
else:
    return ss[lastcomma+1:i]
```

Is there pythonic way of doing this? or is there a better recursive way to parse the whole formula? Many thanks

Comment: openpyxl now has a tokenizer: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formula.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best Excel formula parser I'm aware of is [E. W. Bachtal's algorithm](http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2004/12/excel_formula_p.html).  There's a Python port by Robin Macharg; the most recent version I know about is part of the [pycel project](https://github.com/dgorissen/pycel), but it can be used standalone - [ExcelFormula](https://github.com/dgorissen/pycel/blob/3436e958cc7c2f9258f0d69a53ad5bf74cc6a166/src/pycel/excelformula.py#L548).  It has no problem parsing your formula:

```
from pycel.excelformula import ExcelFormula, FunctionNode
formula = ExcelFormula('=IF(AND(LEN(R[-2]C[-1])>0,R[-1]C),WriteCurve(OFFSET(R16C6, 0,0,R9C7,R10C7),R15C6,R10C3, R8C3),"NONE")')
>>> formula.ast
FunctionNode<IF>
```

You can then walk the AST to find the WriteCurve node and examine its arguments:

```
write_curve = next(node for node, _ in formula.ast.descendants if isinstance(node, FunctionNode) and node.value.strip('(') == 'WriteCurve')
>>> write_curve.children[2].value
'R10C3'
```

Comment: Visit https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formula.html?highlight=token#parsing-formulas for something that works in 2020

Comment: @Motin that only does basic tokenizing, you still need pycel to shunting-yard it into RPN and then AST. I'll look at the current API there.

Comment: @Motin updated to current pycel API. btw thanks for pointing out the need for an update!