# Using openpyxl, how to overwrite data in specific excel sheet linked to pivot tables

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to clear all data in a sheet in excel and replace it with a pandas DataFrame. This sheet is then used in a pivot table in another sheet.
First, what is the best way to replace the data using openpyxl from a pandas DataFrame. Then is it possible to refresh the pivot tables to the new data range?

I found some a few question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426034/openpyxl-overwrite-datasheet-and-preserve-pivot-table) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618680/overwrite-an-excel-sheet-with-pandas-dataframe-without-affecting-other-sheets), but the following doesn't seem to overwrite the data of an existing sheet in an excel file.

```
df = pd.read_csv(PATH)

book = xls.load_workbook(PATH)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(PATH, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='SHEET_NAME',index=False,encoding='utf8')
writer.save()
```

openpyxl has some documentaion about overwriting single cell and row values, but not an entire sheet of data.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I belive to actually refresh a pivot table (or calculate anything) you need to open Excel and make it do that. AFAIK all these excel libraries only read and write, they do not calculate.

Comment: Thanks, that's also what I have mainly found other than using VBA or win32com which is a bit more cumbersome.
Do you know a solution to just clearing a sheet and adding new data to it? I can then just manually update the pivot tables?

Comment: Openpyxl can tell Excel to refresh the pivot. But that is not the problem. If you want to replace data in a particular sheet then that is easy with openpyxl.

Comment: @CharlieClark great, would you be able to tell me how to clear all data in a sheet and replace it with data from a pandas DataFrame using openpyxl?
Thanks!