# What is the best way to write to a sheet without overwriting an excel file?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, excel-writer-xlsx

I have an Excel file named MasterFile. Within MasterFile I have multiple sheets with formulas. I would like to use the code below to update one sheet in MasterFile without overwriting any of my data or formulas.

Here is my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

url = 'http://www.baseballpress.com/lineups'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

players = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'player-link'})]


my_dict = (players)

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(my_dict))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('my2nd_webscrape.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

I have found some info regarding this subject in [How to write to an existing excel file without breaking formulas with openpyxl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262448/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-breaking-formulas-with-openpyxl), but I am not sure how to adjust my code.

Comment: No need for pandas here. And you can prevent overwriting by just using a different filename when saving.

Comment: I appreciate the heads up @CharlieClark! Would it be possible for you to show me an example? I am new to this stuff. I will try my best to figure it out in the meantime. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('my2nd_webscrape.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('my2nd_webscrape.xlsx')
writer.book = book

url = 'http://www.baseballpress.com/lineups'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
players = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'player-link'})]
my_dict = (players)

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(my_dict))
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: I received an error... AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_worksheet'. I will look into this later today. Thanks for getting back to me @Himavanth! =)

Comment: Fyi - `xlwt` and `xlsxwriter` have methods `add_sheet` and `add_worksheet` respectively.
Anyways, happy to help!